# Nest js - circular reference at the moment to inject a repository

Tags: nestjs

Every time I try to run my project, I get the error:

> CircularDependencyException [Error]: A circular dependency has been
> detected inside @InjectRepository(). Please, make sure that each side
> of a bidirectional relationships are decorated with "forwardRef()".
> Also, try to eliminate barrel files because they can lead to an
> unexpected behavior too.

The only clue I have is one of my modules:

If I comment this line:

```
constructor(
        @InjectRepository(Role) private roleRepo: Repository<Role>
    ){}
```

and the project runs, but I notice the log when I start the project, the Module with the error starts before everything

```
[Nest] 16872   - 08/04/2020, 7:56:24 PM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 16872   - 08/04/2020, 7:56:24 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +91ms
[Nest] 16872   - 08/04/2020, 7:56:25 PM   [InstanceLoader] MyErrorModule dependencies initialized +500ms
[Nest] 16872   - 08/04/2020, 7:56:25 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmCoreModule dependencies initialized +630ms
[Nest] 16872   - 08/04/2020, 7:56:25 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +2ms
[Nest] 16872   - 08/04/2020, 7:56:25 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 16872   - 08/04/2020, 7:56:25 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 16872   - 08/04/2020, 7:56:25 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 16872   - 08/04/2020, 7:56:25 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +4ms
[Nest] 16872   - 08/04/2020, 7:56:25 PM   [InstanceLoader] AuthorizationModule dependencies initialized +3ms
[Nest] 16872   - 08/04/2020, 7:56:25 PM   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +3ms
[Nest] 16872   - 08/04/2020, 7:56:25 PM   [InstanceLoader] FirstModule dependencies initialized +2ms
```

But I have my `app.module.ts` file with

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
    useClass: DatabaseConnectionService
  }), 
  AuthorizationModule,
  TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User, Role]),
  FirstModule, 
  SecondModule,
  MyErrorModule, //This is the first to be executed
],
```

Someone has an idea about how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I decided to not delete this question, because it could be helpful for others.

This part of the log was important to debug my issue:

```
[Nest] 16872   - 08/04/2020, 7:56:24 PM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 16872   - 08/04/2020, 7:56:24 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +91ms
[Nest] 16872   - 08/04/2020, 7:56:25 PM   [InstanceLoader] MyErrorModule dependencies initialized +500ms
[Nest] 16872   - 08/04/2020, 7:56:25 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmCoreModule dependencies initialized +630ms
[Nest] 16872   - 08/04/2020, 7:56:25 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +2ms
```

> And I notice one of the modules was registered before everything and
> the reason was: I had an unused `import` in one of my services and
> that import contained another service and that was producing the
> circular reference.

That's why in this thread: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/3555#issuecomment-562468943 written by [Kamil Mysliwiec](https://github.com/kamilmysliwiec)

> This error means that you've passed undefined value into
> @InjectRepository() decorator. We can't really produce anything more
> descriptive :( Ensure you don't have any circular dependencies between
> your entity<->service.

And it's true, with the import I tried to inject an unregistered Module/Service that wasn't ready yet.
So, the solution FOR THIS SPECIFIC CASE, clean the code, and remove the unused imports.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I was having trouble with building tests and got this same error. Turns out I had the wrong import type (`import User` instead of `import { User }`), and because of that quote mentioning passing `undefined` values, I could identify it

Comment: For anyone who might run into this too, the issue in my case was the extra comma here: `imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Auth, User, ,Location])]`

Answer (score 5):

in my case it was because of wrong "paths". I used shorthands for paths using "@" and IDE told me that the path is ok but nest.js said that it was a circular dependecy.

Comment: Same here. If you are in the same module, then realtive path (barrels are ok) have to be uses.

Answer (score 3):

If someone is dealing the same circular dependency error, I found a way to find the problematic code line.

1- First need to install a eslint plugin

```
yarn add -D eslint-plugin-import
```

2- Set the configration in eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": [
    "import",
    // ...
  ],
  "extends": [
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    // ...
  ],
  "rules": {
    "import/no-cycle": 2,
    // ...
  },
  // ...
};
```

After done the above steps, it might need to reload the text editor too.
[Source](https://wanago.io/2022/02/28/api-nestjs-circular-dependencies/)

**09.07.2023 Edit:**  Found another way to check

1- Install madge

```
yarn add -D madge
```

2- Check circular dependencies with providing tsconfig

```
yarn madge --ts-config ./tsconfig.json --circular --extensions js,ts src/
```

Comment: I was able to find the circular reference with *madge*. In my case I use an `index.ts` file which loads everything on the directory and I was like loading `UserService` inside `UserController` (both in the same directory) but instead reference the `UserService` file itself I included it from `index.ts` and I had both `UserController` and `UserService` referenced on the file thus my circular reference found with `madge`.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. For me, it was resolved by reordering imports.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by checking the imports in the respective .module.ts file.

I had renamed an entity but Visual Studio Code didn't pick this particular aspect of the change up, nor did the error log shed any useful light on the root cause of the issue.

Comment: I hadn't noticed (but also didn't know it was necessary to use the TypeORM package) that my entities in various locations were imported backwards. Let's say B depended on A but B was being imported before A and when I corrected the orientation in all codes the problem went away. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was an incorrect error generated by NestJS. I was just starting the project and had an empty array of providers within the module file. In the compiled NestJS code we see that when no providers exist then a circular dependency error is thrown:

[image]

For now I'm just commenting out the providers array altogether:

```
@Module({
  // imports: [ApiAppModule],
  controllers: [UserController],
  // providers: [],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same issue appeared for me after updating Nest to the 10th version. My solution was just changing the order of the imports in the problematic module.

From this:

```
imports: [
  forwardRef(() => UserModule),
  PassportModule,
],
```

to this:

```
imports: [
  PassportModule,
  forwardRef(() => UserModule),
],
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an Entity called "Transaction", my IDE automatically imported a class Transaction. But a class from typeorm.

If youre getting this error, look if all the things you use are imported correctly, wasted way too much time on that